# Docker Desktop Version 2.5.0.0 breaks mounting of volumes inside mounted folders

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Since I upgraded Docker Desktop from 2.4.0.0 to 2.5.0.0 the mounted files appears as empty inside the container.

Example docker-compose.yml

```
  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:7.3
    volumes:
      - ../drupal/:/var/www/html
      - ./settings.php:/var/www/html/web/sites/default/settings.php
```

That creates a mount on /var/www/html inside the container then it mounts a file into /var/www/html/web/sites/default

When I go inside the container, the file is empty.

I was looking into the Release notes https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#bug-fixes-and-minor-changes-1 and it seems there was some work done related to mounting. I suspect that broke things

I found this old issue of very similar problem https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40109

Comment: Interesting, I've not been able to get this to work on prior versions myself.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded Docker Desktop to 2.4.0.0 and it works correctly again.